# Authentication Mechanism for Gupshup WhatsApp pintegration with my own Business API

Tags: authentication, whatsapp, gupshup

What is the best and safest authentication strategy to support Gupshup(WhatsApp) and my own Business API integration? We independently support JWT/Oauth based authentication on our API, but in case of WhatsApp Integration, we will just have a phone number and not a user ID & password.

Comment: Hi Pappu. Could you please add some more information to your question? From what I read you have your own WABA integration. Is it an integration your company is selling to your clients or you limit it internally for yourself only? In other words, you mention you will just have a phone number and not user ID & password. If Gupshup (or anything else) does not provide to you WABA user ID & password, that means WABA owner needs to get this information by themselves. WABA owner may then eventually provide this information to you in any secure way you provide to them.